# Javascript How to update value in array based on matching value in different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to figure out a way to take a string and update values based on a new string that is coming in.  The string represents the structure of a table and contains a column name and a column data type.

To do this I am trying to convert the original string and the new string into arrays.  Then I need to union the results but update existing columns with their new data types.

For instance, in the below example I want to return 4 columns where col2 is updated from varchar(30 to varchar(20).

```
var original_schema = 'col1 int,col2 varchar(30),col3 datetime2,col5 bit';
var new_schema = 'col1 int,col2 varchar(20),col3 datetime2,col4 int';

var arr_original_schema = original_schema.replace(/ /g,':').split(",");
var arr_new_schema = new_schema.replace(/ /g,':').split(",");

console.log(arr_original_schema);
console.log(arr_new_schema);

function arrayUnique(array) {
    var a = array.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {           
            //removed
          if(a[i] === a[j])            
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }

    return a;
}

var uniqueschema = arrayUnique(arr_original_schema.concat(arr_new_schema));
console.log(uniqueschema)
```

**The expected result is:**
**col1 int,col2 varchar(20),col3 datetime2,col4 int,col5 bit"**

Comment: Please add example of final expected result

Comment: Thank you, I added my expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create objects of it, then use Object.assign

```js
const original_schema = 'col1 int,col2 varchar(30),col3 datetime2,col5 bit';
const new_schema = 'col1 int,col2 varchar(20),col3 datetime2,col4 int';

const objectify = (string) => string.split(',').reduce((a, b) => {
    const [col, type] = b.split(/\s+/);
    a[col] = type;
    return a;
}, {});

const os = objectify(original_schema);
const ns = objectify(new_schema);

const res = Object.entries(Object.assign(os, ns)).map(e => e.join(' ')).join(',');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var original_schema = 'col1 int,col2 varchar(30),col3 datetime2';
var new_schema = 'col1 int,col2 varchar(20),col3 datetime2,col4 int';


const arr_1 = original_schema.split(',');
const arr_0 = (new Array(arr_1.length)).fill(null);
let arr_2 = new_schema.split(',')
arr_2=Object.assign(arr_0, arr_2)

const result =  arr_2.filter(function (el) {
  return el != null;
}).join(',')

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This fails to union the schemas correctly; properties from `a` that aren't in `b` aren't carried through.

Comment: "For instance, in the below example I want to return 4 columns where col2 is updated from varchar(30 to varchar(20)." he doesn't want union he wants overriding...

Comment: I'm talking about properties that aren't in `b`. In the example, there's an extra column in `b`, but switch the two around so there's an extra column in `a` that doesn't exist in `b`. For example, `"a int, b int"` and `"a float"` we should get `"a float, b int"`.

Comment: my snippet result is "col1 int,col2 varchar(20),col3 datetime2,col4 int" which is the expected result from the question. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it works on that input but fails on the above case.

Comment: `Object.assign([1,2,3], [4,5,6])` => `Array(3) [ 4, 5, 6 ]`. This is just taking the second array, so `Object.assign` isn't doing anything here.

Comment: Yes - I am in need for all columns to be included, but ones that already exist should be overwritten with the new value.  Thanks for the responses!!!!

Comment: It's almost working, but not quite.  I updated my example to include a column in the original_schema: col5) that new_schema doesn't have and was needing it to persist in the result. I added col5 to show that this was needed.  I really do appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const original_schema = 'col1 int,col2 varchar(30),col3 datetime2,col5 bit';
const new_schema = 'col1 int,col2 varchar(20),col3 datetime2,col4 int';

const originalArr = original_schema.split(",");
const newArr = new_schema.split(",");

// Create single array with duplicates
const mergedArray = [...originalArr, ...newArr];

// Run through merged array with duplicates and create/overwrite existing values
let mergedObj = mergedArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let [id, str] = item.split(' ');
  acc[id] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});

// sort the values of object using local compare
// Assume that each value always start with col and number and they should be ordered as such.
// use localCompare to compre these values.
let sorted = Object.values(mergedObj).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(sorted.join(','));
```